# Am I supposed to be able to see the android scrollbar in the Eclipse Graphical Layout?

Tags: java, android

I put in a scrollview in the XML of my program, and the graphical layout shows all of the fields bunched up in the screen, rather than having a scrollbar on this side and only some of the fields showing up (like I've seen in videos). I was wondering if this was normal, or something with my code or IDE is messed up. I use Eclipse with Windows 7. Thanks :)

My code is nearly identical to this one (the only things changed are the text:, and the IDs).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Email address(es):"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etEmails">
        </EditText>
        <TextView android:text="Hateful Intro:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etIntro"></EditText>
        <TextView android:text="Person's name" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etName"></EditText>
        <TextView android:text="Stupid Things that this Person does"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etThings"></EditText>
        <TextView android:text="What you want to do to this person:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etAction"></EditText>
        <TextView android:text="Hateful Outro" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etOutro"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="40"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Send Email" android:id="@+id/bSentEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></AnalogClock>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: THe eclipse graphical editor is a barely usable POS.  For anything more than the simplest layouts you can't count on it working.  You really need to be able to edit the raw xml and understand what it does.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's just that I saw others' working so I got worried. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the normal behavior (at least on all Eclipse IDEs I have seen before, and on mine).

Comment: Gracias! :) Now I can stop procrastinating.